# nUnit attribute [Retry] does not work in my test

Tags: automated-tests, nunit

I am very new to nUnit testing
I try to use nUnit attributes and in my code [Retry] does not work when Assert fails.
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 Current Version 17.6.2
NuGet packages: Selenium.WebDriver, Selenium.Support, Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver, Gherkin, NUnit, NUnit3TestAdapter

I use in Assert method wrong title (see "Attention! WrongTitle so that Assertion will fail") to make assertion fail.

the code is:

```
using NUnit;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V113.CSS;
using System;


namespace TestThePage
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NavigateToTheWepPage
    {
       
        private IWebDriver driver;

        public IWebDriver theDriver
        {
            get { return driver; }
            set { driver = value; }
        }

        string url = "https://www.Some Web Site I Use to Experiment With nUnit";

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void InitaliseSmth()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
        }

        [Test]
        [Retry(2)]
        public void CallSomeTest()
        {
            //Step 1: Navigate through couple of pages
            OpenSomePage(url);
            IWebElement element = theDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[8]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[5]/a/span[1]"));
            element.Click();
            IWebElement element1 = theDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id=\"orb-modules\"]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a/span[1]"));
            element1.Click();
            
            //element2.Click();
            string currentPageTitle = theDriver.Title;

            // Step 2 Assert you have an expected content on the page you navigated to 
            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(currentPageTitle.Contains("Attention! WrongTitle so that Assertion will fail"));
                TestContext.WriteLine("Word \"World\" was found in the header");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                TestContext.WriteLine("Word \"World\" was NOT found in the header");
                if (ex is AssertionException)
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing failed: {ex.Message}");

            }
        }

        public void OpenSomePage(string url)
        { 
            theDriver.Url = url;
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect that when assertion fails, so because I have [Retry(2)] it would try to run the code again.
However, when I run the code it just fails for the first time and would NOT try to execute again.  Is it my wrong expectation about [Retry(2)] ,or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: It's likely that catching the AssertionException is preventing NUnit from processing the Retry properly. You should never catch NUnit's exceptions since NUnit itself uses them to produce reports, etc. If that doesn't help, please add info to your question showing what NUnit output is from running the test.

Comment: Thank you @Charlie, I managed now to solve the problem.  Sorry, I did not provide full details - my bad.  But I used  [TearDown]  Instead of [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
            theDriver.Close();
        } in my code I changed it to be [OneTimeTearDown] and it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code I changed [TearDown] to [OneTimeTearDown] and it is working now.
It was just closing the driver before the second attempt.

```
using NUnit;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V113.CSS;
using System;


namespace TestThePage
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class NavigateToTheWepPage
    {
       
        private IWebDriver driver;
        //public IWebDriver Driver => driver;

        public IWebDriver theDriver
        {
            get { return driver; }
            set { driver = value; }
        }

        readonly string url = "https://Some web site url";
        int count = 0;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void InitaliseSmth()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
        }

        [Test]
        [Retry(2)]
        [Category("PracticenUnit")]
        public void CallSomeTest()
        {
            //Step 1: Navigate through couple of pages
            OpenSomePage(url);
            IWebElement element = theDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[8]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[5]/a/span[1]"));
            element.Click();
            IWebElement element1 = theDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id=\"orb-modules\"]/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[6]/a/span[1]"));
            element1.Click();
         
            string currentPageTitle = theDriver.Title;

            // Step 2 Assert you have an expected content on the page you navigated to
            try
            {
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("Here it is in try assertion, count: {0}", ++count);
                Assert.IsTrue(currentPageTitle.Contains("Attention! WrongTitle so that Assertion will fail"));
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("Here it is AFTER Assertion");
              
            }
            catch
            {
                TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("In the catch");
            }

            // Step 3 return to the previous page
            ReturnToThePreviousPage();
        }

       
        public void OpenSomePage(string url)
        { 
            theDriver.Url = url;
        }

        public void ReturnToThePreviousPage()
        {
            theDriver.Navigate().Back();
        }

        //[TearDown]
        // public void closeBrowser()
        //{
        //theDriver.Close();
        //}

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void closeBrowser()
        {
            theDriver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now it is running twice before the program is closed, see the Output:

[image]